# Commas not removed Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove all non-alphanumeric characters from a string and then proceed to count the amount of words for each line extracted from a pdf.

```
var m = item["str"].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g," ").trim().split(" ");
console.log("count: " + m.length + " words: " + m);
```

This is the code. An example of the resulting output:

> count: 10 words: The,Quick,Brown,Fox,,,Jumps,Over,The,Lazy

While item["str"] looks like this:

> The Quick Brown Fox - Jumps Over The Lazy

Some output also looks like this:

> count:1 words:

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your regex matches a single character and replaces it with a space. This results in multiple spaces in a row in the final string.

Lets use your example:

```
The Quick Brown Fox - Jumps Over The Lazy
```

becomes

```
The Quick Brown Fox   Jumps Over The Lazy
```

Splitting that by spaces will result in a few empty strings.

---

You should split on multiple spaces in a row to remove them: `split(/\s+/)`.

```js
function runReplace(str) {
  var m = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g," ").trim().split(/\s+/);
  document.write(str + "<br/>");
  document.write("count: " + m.length + " words: " + m + "<br/>");
}

runReplace("The Quick Brown Fox - Jumps Over The Lazy");
```

Comment: `/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/g` doesn't work and `split("\s+")` isn't valid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var item = {
    str: 'The Quick Brown Fox - Jumps Over The Lazy'
};

var output = item['str'].trim().replace(/\W/g, ' ').replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(/\s/);

console.log('length', output.length);
console.log('output', output)
```

I've found 8 words instead of 10 :v

Comment: I'd use `.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` instead of `.replace(/\s{2}/g, '')`. Your code doesn't work properly for double spaces.

Comment: @Cerbrus You're right!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done.Just do one thing remove the empty arguments in Array using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example) Method

```js
var m = "The Quick Brown Fox - Jumps Over The Lazy".replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g," ").trim().split(" ").filter(a=> (a));
console.log("count: " + m.length + " words: " + m.join(","));
```